# How to I calculate the variance around the unrestricted mean in a survival model in Stata?

Tags: stata, survival-analysis

I am doing some exploring with survival analyses. I would like to get the mean survival time of the KM curve when it is extended to zero through extrapolation with the exponential curve. This is built into Stata. After `stset`, one can get the restricted and unrestricted means with `stci, rmean` and `stci, emean` respectively.

Example:

```
use http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/examples/asa2/whas100, clear
stset foltime, id(id) failure(folstatus)
stci, rmean
stci, emean
```

There must be uncertainty surrounding the extrapolated parts. I want to know the standard deviation of the emean. Or even the range.

I searched around on Google and these sites but no luck.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with survival analysis, but based on the documentation for stci it seems that emeans is being calculated (rather than estimated) for an extension of the survival curve, so I'm not sure why there "must be uncertainty surrounding the extrapolated parts" - particularly since the same command provides the standard error for rmean.